# Subroutine with same name in 2 different CPAN modules

Tags: perl, module, subroutine

I am getting this error when running perl:

> [Thu Mar 16 00:24:23 2023] list_directory_1.cgi: Subroutine
> main::getcwd redefined at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/list_directory_1.cgi line
> 15.

I think it is coming from the fact that `getcwd` is defined in CPAN module `Cwd` and also in `POSIX`. How do I specify that this subroutine is to be taken from the `Cwd` module?

Comment: I changed to: use Cwd qw(cwd); Is this correct? What do I need to change for POSIX if I am only using the seek function? How do you find out which symbols are available?

Comment: `use POSIX qw( seek );`. Except `seek` is a builtin. No need to override the builtin `seek` with the one from POSIX.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed, both Cwd and POSIX export `getcwd` by default.

```
$ perl -we'use Cwd; use POSIX;'
Subroutine main::getcwd redefined at -e line 1.
```

The solution is to only import the symbols you need.

```perl
use Cwd      qw( abs_path );
use POSIX    qw( strftime floor );
use DateTime qw( );                  # Import nothing.
```

If you consistently adopt this style of explicitly listing imports, you gain the benefit of being able to see the origin of subs at a glance.

Answer (score 4):

Besides what [ikegami already shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75751291/2766176), there's another way to go. Instead of importing, fully specify which one you want:

```
use Cwd ();  # import nothing

my $dir = Cwd::getcwd();
```

This can be helpful if people know that the function can come from different sources, but don't remember which one you chose.